# Problemas al realizar consultas en Firebase ocnb Kotlin luego de generar el apk de mi proyecto

Tags: firebase, kotlin, subconsultas

tengo el siguiente problema con mi proyecto desarrollado en Kotlin usando Firebase. Al momento de realizar mis pruebas del proyecto todas las operaciones de consulta a la base de datos de Firebase Database funcionan ok, pero al momento de generar el apk firmado para montarla en la google play, por algun motivo las operaciones de consulta no funcionan y lo peor es que no me generan ningun error de ejecución.

Por ejemplo: Realizo una consulta (usando un criterio) de los datos de un nodo, para montarla en un RecyclerView y mientras hago mis pruebas tanto en el dispositivo virtual como en el dispositivo físico utilizando el Android Studio funciona perfecto, pero al generar el apk y montarlo en la Google Play, el recicler me queda vacío realizando exactamente el mismo proceso... Por favor ayudenme, alomejor es una tontería pero es mi primer apk y aun estoy aprendiendo...

Lo más extraño es que el apk firmada y montada en la PlayStore permite el acceso autenticado a la Base de Datos, me permite la escritura en la base de datos y la actualización pero el error es al realizar una consulta y devolver esos datos al reciclerview...

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Prueba ejecutar una versión debug con la misma configuración de la versión release. `buildTypes { debug { debuggable true  // copia y pega aqui la misma configuracion de realese{} } }`

Comment: me explicarías un poquito más porfa, ya que me metí en el build.gradle(app) y allí coloque lo que me recomendaste pero ahora no se que hacer

Comment: ejecutala en el emulador. ¨debug¨ es la versión que se ejecuta por defecto, incluso cuando no está declarada explicitamente en los buildTypes. Si el error se soluciona entonces el problema está en los certificados. Si el error se mantiene es porque lo está causando una de esas configuraciones

Comment: Gracias Sinner!, estoy probando esa opción a ver que podrá ser. Apenas tenga la solucion publico por acá para dar por cerrado el tema

Comment: Perdón, no había leído bien la pregunta. Si las demás consultas estaban funcionando entonces la conexión estaba bien y el problema necesariamente tenía que estar en la configuración de release

Answer (score 0):

Puedo imaginar cual es error. Supongo que en tu configuración "realease" tenes `minifyEnabled true`. Esto elimina todas las clases, propiedades y métodos que aparentemente no se usan. Luego, todo lo que no fue eliminado es renombrado con nombres super cortos para que el tamaño de tu aplicación sea el menor posible.

### Cómo esto puede causar que fallen las consultas?

Supongo que tienes un model para almacenar los resultados de la consulta. Digamos que es este:

```
data class Person(var name: String? = null, var age: Int? = null)
```

Entoces supongo que el dataset en el adapter de tu recyclerView es algo como `val data: List<Person>`

No especifcaste que base de datos de firebase estás usando pero las operaciones de consulta retornan objetos de tipo `DataSnapshot`(realtime database) o `DocumentSnapshot`(firestore).

Supongo que estás creando instancias de tu model a partir estos objetos. Y supongo que lo estás haciendo con los métodos que trae el SDK de firebase, por ejemplo `DataSnapshot.getValue(Person::class.java)` o `DocumentSnapshot.toObject(Person::class.java)`.

El problema es que estos métodos utilizan reflection, es decir que leen la estructura de las clases at runtime. En este ejemplo buscarán propiedades en la clase Person que coincidan con los nombres de las propiedades del objeto consultado a la base datos. Sin embargo, debido a la minification, la clase Person ahora es algo como

```
data class A(var a: String? = null, var b: Int? = null)
```

por lo tanto no encontrarán propiedades llamadas "name" o "age" y la conversión fallará.

### Conclusión

Las operaciones de consulta a la base de datos se están realizando exitosamente pero, al no poder parsear el resultado, el recycler no tiene nada que mostrar.

### Solución

- **opción 1**: Usar la anotación `@Keep` para que la clase mantenga sus nombres:

```
@Keep
data class Person(var name: String? = null, var age: Int? = null)
```

- **opción 2**: Permitir que se acorten los nombres pero usar la anotación `@PropertyName` para que firebase sepa como parsearlo:

```
data class Person(
    @PropertyName("name") var name: String? = null,
    @PropertyName("age") var age: Int? = null
)
```

- **opción 3**: Crear tu propio parser que no utilice reflection.